# Top users for a tag - the 30 day link should link to questions / answers for those 30 days

Tags: feature-request, tags, top-users

In the topusers page for a tag, the 30 day list has links for the questions / answers. But these link to the questions / answers in that tag for the user rather than the last 30 days alone. It will be mighty useful if that were the case.

Comment: I think this has been already proposed, but I cannot find the link right now.

Comment: At the moment we have two divergent interpretations of your Question in our Answers - would you be able to edit your Question to be more explicit, please?

Comment: (As per my understanding) You are referring to [these links](http://i.stack.imgur.com/wYwwg.png), correct? (Feel free to use that image in your question)

Answer (score 1):

When I visit a **[topuser page](https://gis.stackexchange.com/tags/arcgis-desktop/topusers)** for a tag, I too would like to be able to click on the percentage values in the right-hand column of the graphic below and, for example, be able to immediately start reviewing whether I can answer any of the:

- 40% unanswered Questions from the Last 7 days;
- 33% unanswered Questions from the Last 30 days; or
- **[28.8%](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arcgis-desktop?sort=unanswered&pageSize=50)** unanswered Questions from All Time

I have included a link on the All Time percentage above because that has the easiest search syntax to illustrate what I am describing.

[image]

Comment: You do realize you're proposing a different feature to the one OP is proposing, right? That probably should be a separate feature request, not an answer to this one.

Comment: @Dukeling I've just re-read what is in the Question and, although it has no graphic to make what is being asked crystal clear, I do think it is what I have reinforced through my Answer.

Comment: "The 30 day **list** **has** links for the questions / answers ... these link to the questions / answers in that tag **for the user**" - to me, it seems to fairly clearly be referring to already-existing links in the "Top Answerers" or "Top Askers" "Last 30 Days" **user** lists.

Answer (score 0):

I just think we should default to [the newest tab](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=user%3a1711796%20%5balgorithm%5d%20is%3aanswer), not the current default of the relevance tab.

Relevance doesn't really make sense to me in this context.

When clicking on that link, I'm only really interest in ordering by newest, where it's easy to find the 30-day-old line, so I don't really see the need for this (although I'm open to hearing about a different workflow, with justification).