# Provide links from top users page to unanswered lists of questions?

Tags: feature-request, unanswered-questions, top-users

I originally described this in an answer to [Top users for a tag - the 30 day link should link to questions / answers for those 30 days](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118765/top-users-for-a-tag-the-30-day-link-should-link-to-questions-answers-for-tho) and it was suggested that what I was describing warranted a new feature request, so here it is.

When I visit a **[topuser page](https://gis.stackexchange.com/tags/arcgis-desktop/topusers)** for any tag on any site, I would like to be able to click on the percentage values in the right-hand column of the graphic below and, for example, be able to immediately start reviewing whether I can answer any of the:

- 38.6% unanswered Questions from the Last 7 days;
- 38.6% unanswered Questions from the Last 30 days; or
- **[25.3%](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arcgis-desktop?sort=unanswered&pageSize=50)** unanswered Questions from All Time

I have included a link on the All Time percentage (25.3%) above because that has the easiest search syntax to illustrate what I am describing.

[image]